# Accidentally Formatted Red Hat Linux Patition : Getting Grub command prompt

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-7

I have 2 disks on my PC. Disk 0 contains Windows 7 and Ubuntu Wubi installation and Disk 1 contains Red Hat Enterprise Linux Installation. When i used to turn on my PC, i was by default taken to a Red hat linux option menu from where i could choose to run windows 7 or red had. I have accidentally formatted Disk 1 (which contains Red hat linux) when i was working in Windows 7 and upon a reboot, now i am unable to see anything. I am being presented a grub command line, and i have no idea how to boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu. Can someone please guide me on how i can solve this? If i run use a repair/recovery cd for red hat will it be possible to correct this? I donot want to wipe everything since i have some very important data in Disk 0 which contains windows 7 and ubuntu. Please advise.

Comment: You may be able to select Disc 0 in the BIOS and boot from Windows/Wubi. Redhat offer [support](http://www.redhat.com/en/services/support) services which may be of help. Also, this may count as [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here as it not that much about Ubuntu - though [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) can be used to ask questions for Windows, and [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) for Redhat.